# Parse email for title and date, then create an todo in Things (applescript)

Tags: macos, parsing, applescript, apple-mail

I'm new to Applescript and I've built this from code I've found online, and can't really get it to work.

What I want to do is the following

A rule in Apple Mail will trigger the script to find 2 text strings inside the body of the mail.

I want to extract two things from the e-mail

1. Due date (Återlämningsdatum)
2. Title of the book (Titel)

Then I want to create a todo in Things with the title of the book as name of the todo and the due date as due date.

The problem I run into now is that I don't get any data from the mail, just a empty todo is created.

Any ideas?

E-mail below

```
2017-03-22 18:43:55
MALMÖ STADSBIBLIOTEK
Stadsbiblioteket
Låntagarnummer: **********
Utlån
-------------------------
Titel: Ägg : recept & teknik / Tove Nilsson ; [fotografi: Charlie Drevstam]
Exemplarnummer: 3054550018
Återlämningsdatum: 2017-04-19
-------------------------
Antal utlånade material: 1
```

Code below

```
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later
use scripting additions

set subjectText to "Återlämningsdatum: "
set contentSearch to "Titel: "

using terms from application "Mail"
    on perform mail action with messages theMessages for rule theRule
        tell application "Mail"
            set theContent to content
            set theDate to my getFirstWordAfterSearchText(subjectText, theContent)
            set theTitle to my getFirstWordAfterSearchText(contentSearch, theContent)
        end tell
    end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from

tell application "Things3"
    set newToDo to make new to do
    set name of newToDo to theTitle
    set due date of newToDo to theDate
end tell

(*============== SUBROUTINES =================*)
on getFirstWordAfterSearchText(searchString, theText)
    try
        set {tids, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, searchString}
        set textItems to text items of theText
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tids
        return (first word of (item 2 of textItems))
    on error theError
        return ""
    end try
end getFirstWordAfterSearchText
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my testing, your script returns the following values:

```
theDate: "2017"
theTitle: "Ägg"
```

So, I'm assuming you should perhaps get a blank to-do named "Ägg" ?  If not, you could try:

```
    tell application "Things3" to make new to do with properties ¬
        {name: theTitle, due date: theDate}
```

(although I neither use nor own *Things 3*, so cannot test this for you).

Anyway, to address the original problem, the issue is in only asking your handler `getFirstWordAfterSearchText` to return the `first word`.  I don't speak Swedish, but it looks to me that the title contains more than one word.  The date most definitely does, as each word is separated by a hyphen (which is considered a non-word character in AppleScript).

My suggestion would be to split the email content into paragraphs, isolate the lines of text that start with either "Titel" or "Återlämningsdatum", then return those lines, excluding any unwanted words.  Here's a handler that does this:

```
    to getFirstParagraphThatStarts on searchString ¬
        from theText ¬
        apart from excludedStrings : null
        local searchString, theText, excludedStrings

        repeat with P in theText's paragraphs
            if P starts with the searchString then exit repeat
        end repeat

        set the text item delimiters to {null} & the excludedStrings
        text items of P as text
    end getFirstParagraphThatStarts
```

I called the handler much like you did yours:

```
    set theDate to getFirstParagraphThatStarts on subjectText from theContent
    set theTitle to getFirstParagraphThatStarts on contentSearch from theContent
```

(I omitted the `apart from` parameter to begin with, to test the return result before any exclusions were imposed).  The return result was this:

```
theDate: "Återlämningsdatum: 2017-04-19"
theTitle: "Titel: Ägg : recept & teknik / Tove Nilsson ; [fotografi: Charlie Drevstam]"
```

Then I added in the `apart from` parameter:

```
    set theDate ¬
        to getFirstParagraphThatStarts on subjectText ¬
        from theContent ¬
        apart from subjectText

    set theTitle ¬
        to getFirstParagraphThatStarts on contentSearch ¬
        from theContent ¬
        apart from contentSearch
```

and the return results were as follows:

```
theDate: "2017-04-19"
theTitle: "Ägg : recept & teknik / Tove Nilsson ; [fotografi: Charlie Drevstam]"
```

which, I *think*, is more along the lines of what you are wanting.

---

#### ADDENDUM 1: Dates

Another thought I had regarding *Things 3* is that the `due date` property might require an actual AppleScript `date` object, rather than just a string that looks like it might be a date.  That is, `"2017-04-19"` might not be a valid `due date`.  Again, I neither use nor own *Things 3*, so this is just speculation.

AppleScript date formats are intrinsically tied to your system settings.  As I have my system date/time preferences set to use international ISO-8601 date representations, i.e. `yyyy-mm-dd`, I can create the AppleScript date object straight from `theDate` variable like so:

```
date theDate
```

If this is the case with you, and it turns out that you *do* require a `date` object, then you can simply `set due date of newToDo to date theDate`, or (if using my suggested code from above):

```
    tell application "Things3" to make new to do with properties ¬
        {name: theTitle, due date: date theDate}
```

If, however, your system settings are set differently, you'll need to construct the AppleScript `date` object yourself.  Here's a handler that will do this:

```
    to makeASdate out of {year:y, month:m, day:d}
        local y, m, d

        tell (the current date) to set ¬
            [ASdate, year, its month, day, time] to ¬
            [it, y, m, d, 0]

        ASdate
    end makeASdate
```

You would then use your `theDate` variable with this handler like so:

```
    makeASdate out of {year:word 1, month:word 2, day:word 3} of theDate
        --> date "Wednesday, 19 April 2017 at 0:00:00"
```

---

#### ADDENDUM 2: Scripting Mail (added 2018-08-12)

After further testing and debugging, you've found that there are other issues with your script that stop it from functioning.  This was an oversight on my part, as I ought to have highlighted these errors initially, but became focussed on your handler returning incomplete strings that I neglected to come back to the rest of the script and address its other problems.

The problem section, as you've discerned, is this one here:

> ```
> using terms from application "Mail"
>     on perform mail action with messages theMessages for rule theRule
>         tell application "Mail"
>             set theContent to content
>             set theDate to my getFirstWordAfterSearchText(subjectText, theContent)
>             set theTitle to my getFirstWordAfterSearchText(contentSearch, theContent)
>         end tell
>     end perform mail action with messages
> end using terms from
> ```

You `tell application "Mail"` to `set theContent to content`, however, you haven't specified what the `content` belongs to (or, rather, implicitly, you've specified that the `content` belongs to `application "Mail"`, which it doesn't).

Presumably, you wish to refer to the `content` of `theMessages` that are sent through to this script by your mail rules ?

The other major thing to note is that **`on perform mail action with messages`** is an event handler, i.e. it responds to an event taking place in *Mail*, which causes the handler to be invoked.  Defining other handlers  elsewhere in the script is perfectly fine; but having stray lines of code that don't belong to any explicit handler will therefore belong to an *implicit* (hidden) **`on run`** handler.  This, in a way, is an event handler as well: it responds to a script being run, which is problematic if the script is also being asked to respond to a *Mail* event simultaneously.

Therefore, the `tell app "Things3"` block needs to be moved, and I imagine the variable declarations at the beginning need to be housed as well.

Bearing all this in mind, I reworked your script to quite a large extent, whilst also trying to keep it resembling your original so it was somewhat recognisable:

```
    using terms from application "Mail"
        on perform mail action with messages theMessages for rule theRule
            set dateToken to "Återlämningsdatum: "
            set titleToken to "Titel: "

            repeat with M in theMessages
                set theContent to getMessageContent for M

                set datum to restOfLineMatchedAtStart by dateToken from theContent
                set titel to restOfLineMatchedAtStart by titleToken from theContent

                if false is not in [datum, titel] then
                    set D to makeASdate out of (datum's words as list)
                    createToDoWithDueDate on D given name:titel
                end if
            end repeat

        end perform mail action with messages
    end using terms from


    to makeASdate out of {Y, M, D}
        local Y, M, D

        tell (the current date) to set ¬
            [ASdate, year, its month, day, time] to ¬
            [it, Y, M, D, 0]

        ASdate
    end makeASdate


    to createToDoWithDueDate on D as date given name:N as text
        tell application "Things3" to make new to do ¬
            with properties {name:N, due date:D}
    end createToDoWithDueDate


    to getMessageContent for msg
        local msg

        tell application "Mail" to return msg's content
    end getMessageContent


    on restOfLineMatchedAtStart by searchString from theText
        local searchString, theText

        ignoring white space
            repeat with P in theText's paragraphs
                if P starts with the searchString then
                    set i to (length of searchString) + (offset of searchString in P)
                    try
                        return text i thru -1 of P
                    on error -- matched entire line
                        return ""
                    end try
                end if
            end repeat
        end ignoring

        false -- no match
    end restOfLineMatchedAtStart
```

Now, as I don't use *Mail* and cannot test these mail rules out myself, there could be one or two minor tweaks that you'll discover need to be made before it's running properly.  On the other hand, it might run correctly as it is, which would amaze me.  But, having spent a lot of time thinking about each line of code, I'm hopeful it's close to what you need.

The major change you can see is that every piece of code now belongs inside a handler.  The custom handlers each get called from inside the main event handler, **`on perform mail action with messages`**.  I also changed some of the variable names, mainly as part of my mental debugging that was going on (I changed them several times, and have left them to what their last meaningful label was in my head).

Let me know how it goes.  Report back any errors.

**NOTE:** Don't forget, however, that this script is designed to be called by the *Mail* application in response to a mail rule being actioned.  Running it from within *Script Editor* will not do anything.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was incredibly kind of you @CJK!
I've added the changes that you gave me and now I don't get any todo at all. I tried to add a dialog that shows the collected data after the tell mail, but that doesn't show either. I tried to break out the "tell things" into a separate code just to see if that works with date and title, and it does. So I guess something happends after the mail script. How can I debug this?

Comment: Which version of `tell app "Things3"` worked: yours or mine, or both ?  I'll make an edit to my post detailing the problems with the rest of your script.

Comment: Both worked, but inside the script, following the mail part, nothings happens

Comment: Please check my edit **`"Addendum 2"`** for my update.

Comment: **NOTE:** Don't forget that this script is designed to be called by the _Mail_ application in response to a mail rule being actioned, as dictated by your use of the **`on perform mail action with messages`**.  Running it from inside _Script Editor_ will **not** do anything.

Comment: Also, I found [this PDF](https://culturedcode.com/things/download/Things3AppleScriptGuide.pdf) online which might be of use to you if you plan to script _Things_ further.  You may know about it already, as it comes from the website of the makers of _Things_.

Comment: That worked flawlessly! Thank you so much! I'd like to add one more thing. I've tried to use schedule like it's used in the PDF about Things 3 but I can't get it to work, not ever if I use "current date". I'd like it to use the date D - 7 days.
I tried to add "schedule for D - 7 * days"
But it it just doesn't add a schedule date.

Comment: I think you would create your To Do: `tell app "Things3" to set newToDo to make new to do with properties...`, then maybe schedule it like this: `tell app "Things3" to schedule newToDo for (D - 7*days)`.